# Bash: Creating subdirectories reading from a file

Tags: bash, subdirectory

I have a file that contains some keywords and I intend to create subdirectories into the same directory of the same keyword using a bash script. Here is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to be working.
I don't know where I have gone wrong. Help me out

```
for i in `cat file.txt`
do
#        if [[ ! -e $path/$i ]]; then
            echo "creating" $i "directory"
            mkdir $path/$i
#       fi
            grep $i file >> $path/$i/output.txt
done
echo "created the files in "$path/$TEMP/output.txt
```

Comment: Show `file.txt` contents.

Comment: do you get an error? which one?

Comment: @anishsane file.txt contains (ABC,DEF,GHI,KJL each in every row)
Never mind, I got it. It was one of the most silly mistakes I have ever made.
The path was wrong. 
Thanks for the answers. :)
Good day.

Comment: `cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 -IDIR mkdir -p $path/DIR`

Answer (score 0):

You've gone wrong [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and you've gone wrong [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

```
while read i
do
  echo "Creating $i directory"
  mkdir "$path/$i"
  grep "$i" file >> "$path/$i"/output.txt
done < file.txt
echo "created the files in $path/$TEMP/output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

78`mkdir` will refuse to create a directory, if parts of it do not exist.
e.g. if there is no `/foo/bar` directory, then `mkdir /foo/bar/baz` will fail.

you can relax this a bit by using the `-p` flag, which will create parent directories if necessary (in the example, it might create `/foo` and `/foo/bar`).

you should also use quotes, in case your paths contain blanks.

```
mkdir -p "${path}/${i}"
```

finally, make sure that you are actually allowed to create directories in `$path`